# LDAP Error "User Name Not Found"

Tags: active-directory, spring-security, ldap

When users try to log onto my web app, an LDAP error, `code 49 data 525`, occurs, which means `username not found`. [LDAP Errors](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors)

I don't know if my resource account, which authenticates to my LDAP server, has a bad username OR whether it's the users trying to log onto my system.

How can I figure this out?

```
>     org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment:
> AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, v1772^@]; nested exception is
> javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 800\
>     90308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, v1772^@]
>             at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:182)
>             at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:266)
>             at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:106)
>             at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:125)
>             at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:287)
>             at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:361)
>             at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:215)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my issue, I had incorrectly entered the DN of the particular LDAP user. I had failed to escape the comma in `CN=Smith\, John`.

After adding the backslash, I got another LDAP error `error code 49 data 52e`, whcih means bad username & password.

Nonetheless, it was an escaping issue.